# Accion en la nueva politica de publicidad de AdMob

Tags: android, flutter, admob

Alguien sabe lo que realmente nos están mandando a hacer la Play Console?
A que se refieren con dirigirse a Android 13 o superior? y demás?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google aplicará este cambio a partir de Abril del 2022, en teoría los plugins/packages que usas deberían tener agregado ese permiso de AD_ID, para que se pueda obtener el ID de anuncio del usuario, de otro modo como dice ahí, te retornará ceros, pero eso solo afectaría a la plataforma de anuncios.

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar en el `AndroidManifest.xml` este permiso (en el caso de que el package/plugin ya lo tenga declarado, no afecta en nada):

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

Esto solo aplica para dispositivos que tengan Android 12 para arriba.

Más info: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=es